# Why would \x escaped URLs appear in my WAMP server logs?

Tags: apache-log-files, web-traffic

I have set up a local WAMP on my server which is accessible over the internet. What is this strange traffic?

[image: screenshot of \x requests]

Normal request traffic would look like this: `/directiory/index.php`, but those requests are escape characters?  Who would access my server like this?

Comment: A log of all the accesses to your server, actually!

Comment: It might be useful to see the "user agent" column from the log files as well.

Comment: Would be interesting but this appache log doesn't contain the user agent column.